# How to parse plain text with multiple data into arrays in php

Tags: php, arrays, parsing, txt

Please I need help
i have try many search on google but couldn't find any useful result
so i decide to ask it here

I have a .txt file containing this info or it can also be a **$variable** containing this info

```
---------Personal info ------------
First Name: Fidelis
Last Name: Peter
-----------Account Info ---------
ID: HTY15gd
Username: fidelisepeter
---------More ---------
About: A graphic designer

---------Personal info ------------
First Name: Fidelis
Last Name: Peter
-----------Account Info ---------
ID: HTY15gd
Username: fidelisepeter
---------More ---------
About: A graphic designer

---------Personal info ------------
First Name: Elis
Last Name: Peter
-----------Account Info ---------
ID: HTY15gd
Username: fidenew
```

I want result like this in an array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [first_name] => Fidelis
            [last_name] => Peter
            [Id] => HTY15gd
            [username] => fidelisepeter
            [about] => graphic designer
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [first_name] => Peter
            [last_name] => Fidelis
            [Id] => HTY15gd
            [username] => fidelisepeter
            [about] => web developer
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [first_name] => Fidelis
            [last_name] => Peter
            [Id] => HTY15gd
            [username] => fidelisepeter
        )

)
```

I don't know how to go about it
Please anyone to help please

Comment: Do you define the .txt file?  Or, do you get it from somewhere?  Can you just write the .txt file in PHP array format and include it when needed?

Comment: i will get the file from a form input

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a top-down parser.

```php
<?php
$input = <<<EOT
---------Personal info ------------
First Name: Fidelis
Last Name: Peter
-----------Account Info ---------
ID: HTY11gd
Username: fidelisepeter
---------More ---------
About: A graphic designer

---------Personal info ------------
First Name: Fidelis
Last Name: Peter
-----------Account Info ---------
ID: HTY12gd
Username: fidelisepeter
---------More ---------
About: A graphic designer

---------Personal info ------------
First Name: Elis
Last Name: Peter
-----------Account Info ---------
ID: HTY13gd
Username: fidenew
EOT;

function error($message, $input, $pos)
{
    $BLUE = "\033[34m";
    $RED = "\033[31m";
    $RESET = "\033[0m";
    $ss = substr($input, $pos, 10);
    $preview = json_encode($ss);
    echo "Error: $BLUE$message$RESET at position $pos (got $RED$preview$RESET):\n";
    $stack = debug_backtrace();
    echo ord($ss[0]);
    echo "backtrace: \n";
    foreach ($stack as $frame) {
        echo $frame['file'] . ':' . $frame['line'] . "\n";
    }
    exit;
}

function match_and_eat($input, $pos, $lit_pattern)
{
    $len = strlen($lit_pattern);
    $from_input = substr($input, $pos, $len);
    if ($from_input == $lit_pattern) {
        return $len;
    }
    return 0;
}

function match_regex_and_eat($input, $pos, $regex_pattern)
{
    // return [length of matched string, string]
    $preview = substr($input, $pos, 10);
    preg_match($regex_pattern, substr($input, $pos), $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
    $regex_pattern = json_encode($regex_pattern);
    if (count($matches) > 0) {
        // echo "matched with $regex_pattern" . "\n";
        // var_dump($matches);
        return [strlen($matches[0][0]), $matches[0][0]];
    }
    // echo "not matched with $regex_pattern at $preview" . "\n";
    return [0, ""];
}



function parse_all($input)
{
    $pos_init = 0;
    $pos = 0;
    $result = [];
    while ($pos < strlen($input)) {
        [$delta, $person] = parse_person($input, $pos);
        if (!$person) {
            error("Failed to parse person", $input, $pos);
        }
        $result[] = $person;
        $pos += $delta;
    }
    return [$pos - $pos_init, $result];
}


function parse_person($input, $pos)
{
    $pos_init = $pos;
    [$delta, $person] = parse_struct($input, $pos, 'Personal info');
    // var_dump($person);
    $pos += $delta;
    [$delta, $account] = parse_struct($input, $pos, 'Account Info');
    // var_dump($account);
    $pos += $delta;
    [$delta, $more] = parse_struct($input, $pos, 'More', false);
    // var_dump($more);
    $pos += $delta;
    $person['account'] = $account;
    $person['more'] = $more;
    return [$pos - $pos_init, $person];
}

function parse_struct($input, $pos, $struct_name, $required = true)
{
    $pos_init = $pos;
    [$delta, $_] = match_regex_and_eat($input, $pos, "/^[ \r\n\t]*/");
    $pos += $delta;
    [$delta, $_] = match_regex_and_eat($input, $pos, '/^\-+/');
    $pos += $delta;
    $delta = match_and_eat($input, $pos, $struct_name);
    $pos += $delta;
    if (!$delta) {
        if ($required) {
            error("Failed to parse $struct_name", $input, $pos);
        } else {
            return [0, null];
        }
    }

    [$delta, $_] = match_regex_and_eat($input, $pos, "/^[ \r\n\t]*/");
    $pos += $delta;

    [$delta, $_] = match_regex_and_eat($input, $pos, '/^\-+/');
    $pos += $delta;

    $personal_info = [];

    while (1) {

        [$delta, $_] = match_regex_and_eat($input, $pos, "/^[ \r\n\t]*/");
        $pos += $delta;

        [$delta, $key] = match_regex_and_eat($input, $pos, "/^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+/");
        $pos += $delta;
        if (!$delta) {
            break;
        }
        [$delta, $_] = match_regex_and_eat($input, $pos, "/^: */");
        $pos += $delta;
        [$delta, $value] = match_regex_and_eat($input, $pos, "/^[^\n]*/");
        $pos += $delta;
        if (!$delta) {
            error("Expect value for $key", $input, $pos);
        }
        $personal_info[$key] = $value;
    }
    return [$pos - $pos_init, $personal_info];
}

$persons = parse_all($input);
var_dump($persons[1]);
```

Output:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    ["First Name"]=>
    string(7) "Fidelis"
    ["Last Name"]=>
    string(5) "Peter"
    ["account"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["ID"]=>
      string(7) "HTY11gd"
      ["Username"]=>
      string(13) "fidelisepeter"
    }
    ["more"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["About"]=>
      string(18) "A graphic designer"
    }
  }
  [1]=>
  array(4) {
    ["First Name"]=>
    string(7) "Fidelis"
    ["Last Name"]=>
    string(5) "Peter"
    ["account"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["ID"]=>
      string(7) "HTY12gd"
      ["Username"]=>
      string(13) "fidelisepeter"
    }
    ["more"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["About"]=>
      string(18) "A graphic designer"
    }
  }
  [2]=>
  array(4) {
    ["First Name"]=>
    string(4) "Elis"
    ["Last Name"]=>
    string(5) "Peter"
    ["account"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["ID"]=>
      string(7) "HTY13gd"
      ["Username"]=>
      string(7) "fidenew"
    }
    ["more"]=>
    NULL
  }
}
```

If you only need flat struct:

```php
<?php
$input = <<<EOT
---------Personal info ------------
First Name: Fidelis
Last Name: Peter
-----------Account Info ---------
ID: HTY11gd
Username: fidelisepeter
---------More ---------
About: A graphic designer

---------Personal info ------------
First Name: Fidelis
Last Name: Peter
-----------Account Info ---------
ID: HTY12gd
Username: fidelisepeter
---------More ---------
About: A graphic designer

---------Personal info ------------
First Name: Elis
Last Name: Peter
-----------Account Info ---------
ID: HTY13gd
Username: fidenew
EOT;

// split by double newline
$blocks = explode("\n\n", $input);
$people = [];
foreach ($blocks as $block) {
    $person = [];
    // split by newline
    $lines = explode("\n", $block);
    foreach ($lines as $line) {
        // split by colon
        $parts = explode(":", $line);
        if(count($parts) != 2) {
            // skip if not 2 parts
            continue;
        }
        // get the key and value
        $key = trim($parts[0]);
        $value = trim($parts[1]);
        // add to the person array
        $person[$key] = $value;
    }
    // add to the people array
    $people[] = $person;
}

var_dump($people);
```

Comment: Thank you very much
But what if want to ignore the commens ---------Personal Info -----Account Info, and -------- More
I just need all info in an array

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your repeat blocks of text are reliably structured. Until you have reason so implement a more dynamic parser, just write a regex to capture the known lines and make the "about" data optional.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/hYRfY))

```
$regex = <<<REGEX
/^-+Personal\hinfo\h-+\R
First\hName:\h(.*)\R
Last\hName:\h(.*)\R
^-+Account\hInfo\h-+\R
ID:\h(\S+)\R
Username:\h(.+)
(?:\R
  ^-+More\h-+\R
  About:\h(.+)?
)?
/mx
REGEX;

$result = [];
preg_match_all($regex, $text, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
foreach ($matches as $i => $m) {
    [,
        $result[$i]['first_name'],
        $result[$i]['last_name'],
        $result[$i]['Id'],
        $result[$i]['username'],
    ] = $m;
    if (isset($m[5])) {
        $result[$i]['about'] = $m[5];
    }
}
var_export($result);
```